# Are we allowed to distribute code generated by early-access JDK builds?

Tags: java

Oracle publishes "early access" JDK builds. For example, currently the latest version of Java is version 11 but "early access" JDK builds of version 12 and 13 are out. As far as I can tell, early access build shave the same licensing terms as final releases.

Some bugs have only been fixed in these early access builds and are not scheduled to be back-ported. As such, does anything (legally or technically) prevent us from compiling our code with JDK 12-ea using `--release 11` and publishing the resulting code as if it was generated by JDK 11?

Comment: 1) This is a legal question, and off-topic.  2)  Check what the license terms say ... and ask your lawyers, or ask Oracle for clarification.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question ... and programmers should not ask other programmers about important legal questions.   (The "I read it on the internet" defense will not stand up in a law court.)